# Codedeploy gets stuck in pending state for the Before install page

Tags: django, amazon-web-services

I am trying to deploy a python django todo application and my code deploy gets stuck in the pending status for the `BeforeInstall` phase:

[image: 0]
[image: 1]
[image: 2]

and eventually fails with the error:

> CodeDeploy agent was not able to receive the lifecycle event. Check the CodeDeploy agent logs on your host and make sure the agent is running and can connect to the CodeDeploy server.

I checked all the permissions and the code deploy agent status also seems to be running not sure what is causing this problem

Answer (score 0):

If you are running an Amazon Linux, RedHat or Ubuntu OS then as per the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/deployments-view-logs.html) try looking in:

```
/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/deployment-logs/codedeploy-agent-deployments.log
```

Look for the logging after the `LifecycleEvent - BeforeInstall` entry.

Also, is there a specific reason you are using `#!/bin/sh` as opposed to `#!/bin/bash` in your `before-install.sh` script? Just curious.